# Too may errors occur in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm practicing iOS app programming by watching *Stanford for iOS* (before 6 years) and these

codes are when it comes to *facial expression app*.

Here are *FaceView* module part of the app(the Model, among MVCs)

and these codes are correct logic and grammar in terms of Swift

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class FaceView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable
    var scale: CGFloat = 0.90 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable
    var mouthCurvature: Double = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } } // 1 full smile, -1 full frown
    @IBInspectable
    var eyesOpen: Bool = true { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable
    var eyeBrowTilt: Double = 0.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } } // 1 fully relaxed, -1 full furrow
    @IBInspectable
    var color: UIColor = UIColor.blue { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 5.0 { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    
    func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .changed, .ended:
            scale *= recognizer.scale
            recognizer.scale = 1.0
        default:
            break
        }
    }
...
```

But I just imitate what this video lectures this is what happened!

```
import UIKit

class FaceViewController: UIViewController {

    var expression = FacialExpression(eyes: .Open, eyeBrows: .Normal, mouth: .Smile) {
        didSet {
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView! {
        didSet {
            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPinchGestureRecognizer(
                target:faceView, action: #selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:)) **Type 'FaceView' has no member 'changeScale'**
            ))
            let happierSwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FaceViewController.increaseHappiness)
            )
            happierSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = .up
            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(happierSwipeGestureRecognizer)
            
            let sadderSwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FaceViewController.decreaseHappiness)
            )
            sadderSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = .down
            faceView.addGestureRecognizer(sadderSwipeGestureRecognizer)
            
            updateUI()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func increaseHappiness() {
        expression.mouth = expression.mouth.happierMouth() **Value of type 'FacialExpression.Mouth' has no member 'happierMouth'**
    }
    
    @objc func decreaseHappiness() {
        expression.mouth = expression.mouth.sadderMouth() **Value of type 'FacialExpression.Mouth' has no member 'sadderMouth'**
    }
    
    private var mouthCurvatures = [FacialExpression.Mouth.Frown: -1.0, .Grin: 0.5, .Smile: 1.0, .Smirk: -0.5, .Neutral: 0.0]
    private var eyeBrowTilts = [FacialExpression.EyeBrows.Relaxed: 0.5, .Furrowed: -0.5, .Normal: 0.0]
    
    private func updateUI() {
        switch expression.eyes {
        case .Open: faceView.eyesOpen = true
        case .Closed: faceView.eyesOpen = false
        case .Squinting: faceView.eyesOpen = false
        }
        faceView.mouthCurvature = mouthCurvatures[expression.mouth] ?? 0.0
        faceView.eyeBrowTilt = eyeBrowTilts[expression.eyeBrows] ?? 0.0
    }
    
    @IBAction func toggleEyes(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .ended { **Cannot find 'recognizer' in scope**
            switch expression.eyes {
            case .Open: expression.eyes = .Closed
            case .Closed: expression.eyes = .Open
            case .Squinting: break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

cf) I described detailed errors '** ~ **' mark signs

Answer (score 0):

Some of your issues might be due to carelessness, but I'm afraid that in general the real reason is that you're using a *very* old tutorial and the Swift language has completely changed since then. For example, nowadays you would need to change

```
 func changeScale(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
```

to

```
 func changeScale(_ recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer)
```

(note the underscore) in order for the rest of your code to compile, i.e. so that `#selector(FaceView.changeScale(_:))` matches the method signature. But you have no way of knowing that; I think your best bet here is to abandon this tutorial, as it will do you more harm than good — it is just too old.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Anything else instead give up?